# JSON style declaration for day-mode Android Maps API

Tags: android, json, google-maps, android-mapview, android-maps-v2

When styling Google Maps views, does anyone know what the JSON style declaration for the day mode is? I've searched many areas online but can't find it.

**JSON style declaration for day-mode**

?

**JSON style declaration for night-mode**

```
<string name="style_json">
  [
    {
      \"featureType\": \"all\",
      \"elementType\": \"geometry\",
      \"stylers\": [
        {
          \"color\": \"#242f3e\"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      \"featureType\": \"all\",
      \"elementType\": \"labels.text.stroke\",
      \"stylers\": [
        {
          \"lightness\": -80
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      \"featureType\": \"administrative\",
      \"elementType\": \"labels.text.fill\",
      \"stylers\": [
        {
          \"color\": \"#746855\"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      \"featureType\": \"administrative.locality\",
      \"elementType\": \"labels.text.fill\",
      \"stylers\": [
        {
          \"color\": \"#d59563\"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      \"featureType\": \"poi\",
      \"elementType\": \"labels.text.fill\",
      \"stylers\": [
        {
          \"color\": \"#d59563\"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      \"featureType\": \"poi.park\",
      \"elementType\": \"geometry\",
      \"stylers\": [
        {
          \"color\": \"#263c3f\"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      \"featureType\": \"poi.park\",
      \"elementType\": \"labels.text.fill\",
      \"stylers\": [
        {
          \"color\": \"#6b9a76\"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      \"featureType\": \"road\",
      \"elementType\": \"geometry.fill\",
      \"stylers\": [
        {
          \"color\": \"#2b3544\"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      \"featureType\": \"road\",
      \"elementType\": \"labels.text.fill\",
      \"stylers\": [
        {
          \"color\": \"#9ca5b3\"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      \"featureType\": \"road.arterial\",
      \"elementType\": \"geometry.fill\",
      \"stylers\": [
        {
          \"color\": \"#38414e\"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      \"featureType\": \"road.arterial\",
      \"elementType\": \"geometry.stroke\",
      \"stylers\": [
        {
          \"color\": \"#212a37\"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      \"featureType\": \"road.highway\",
      \"elementType\": \"geometry.fill\",
      \"stylers\": [
        {
          \"color\": \"#746855\"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      \"featureType\": \"road.highway\",
      \"elementType\": \"geometry.stroke\",
      \"stylers\": [
        {
          \"color\": \"#1f2835\"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      \"featureType\": \"road.highway\",
      \"elementType\": \"labels.text.fill\",
      \"stylers\": [
        {
          \"color\": \"#f3d19c\"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      \"featureType\": \"road.local\",
      \"elementType\": \"geometry.fill\",
      \"stylers\": [
        {
          \"color\": \"#38414e\"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      \"featureType\": \"road.local\",
      \"elementType\": \"geometry.stroke\",
      \"stylers\": [
        {
          \"color\": \"#212a37\"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      \"featureType\": \"transit\",
      \"elementType\": \"geometry\",
      \"stylers\": [
        {
          \"color\": \"#2f3948\"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      \"featureType\": \"transit.station\",
      \"elementType\": \"labels.text.fill\",
      \"stylers\": [
        {
          \"color\": \"#d59563\"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      \"featureType\": \"water\",
      \"elementType\": \"geometry\",
      \"stylers\": [
        {
          \"color\": \"#17263c\"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      \"featureType\": \"water\",
      \"elementType\": \"labels.text.fill\",
      \"stylers\": [
        {
          \"color\": \"#515c6d\"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      \"featureType\": \"water\",
      \"elementType\": \"labels.text.stroke\",
      \"stylers\": [
        {
          \"lightness\": -20
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
</string>
```

**Android Maps day-mode**

[image]
<sub>(source: [vogella.com](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidGoogleMaps/img/xmaps30.png.pagespeed.ic.pOWOxSGBLl.jpg))</sub>

**Android Maps night-mode**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MapView not returning to normal state after clicking toggle switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39811505/mapview-not-returning-to-normal-state-after-clicking-toggle-switch)

The map needs to be set to `null` in order to clear and previous styling

> Set to null to clear any previous custom styling.

```
@Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked){
                boolean success = mGoogleMap.setMapStyle(new MapStyleOptions(getResources()
                        .getString(R.string.style_json)));

                if (!success) {
                    Log.e("TabFragmentMap", "Style parsing failed.");
                }
            } else {
                boolean success = mGoogleMap.setMapStyle(null);

                if (!success) {
                    Log.e("TabFragmentMap", "Removing style failed.");
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

I think Normal mode is interchangeable with Day mode in Google Maps. If you check this [google forum question](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/maps/27GAKCDin2I/SKS40HqrG_cJ), the user calls it "normal day mode" which means they pertain to the one thing.

Check the [styling mode for Android Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/styling) for further reading.