# MapView not returning to normal state after clicking toggle switch

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-maps-v2, android-switch

I'm trying to get my map view to return to the normal style when I flick the switch within my fragment to the the OFF position but it's not working. The following is what occurs during the process that I am facing:

1. Fragment (containg map) and switch appeared
2. Flicked switch to ON position
3. Styled map appeared
4. Flicked switch to OFF position
5. Map doesn't change

I tried using `mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);` but the map still remains stuck on the styled map view when I flick the switch. Not really sure as to what has gone wrong. What must be done to resolve this problem?

```
public class FragmentMap extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private SwitchCompat swt;

    public FragmentMap() {
    }

    GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    MapView mMapView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);

        mMapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.map_park);
        mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mMapView.getMapAsync(this);

        swt = (SwitchCompat) v.findViewById(R.id.switch_map_park);
        swt.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked){
                    boolean success = mGoogleMap.setMapStyle(new MapStyleOptions(getResources()
                            .getString(R.string.style_json)));

                    if (!success) {
                        Log.e("TabFragmentMap", "Style parsing failed.");
                    }
                }else{
                    // What goes here?
                    mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                }
            }
        });

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mGoogleMap = googleMap;
        mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        mGoogleMap.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
        mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mMapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mMapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mMapView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        mMapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mMapView.onLowMemory();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `else` code, you are using `setMapType` while you should be using `setMapStyle` with a `null` parameter to clear the previously set styling, as mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#setMapStyle(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MapStyleOptions)).

> Set to null to clear any previous custom styling.

So, your code should go like this:

```
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked){
                boolean success = mGoogleMap.setMapStyle(new MapStyleOptions(getResources()
                        .getString(R.string.style_json)));

                if (!success) {
                    Log.e("TabFragmentMap", "Style parsing failed.");
                }
            }else{
                boolean success = mGoogleMap.setMapStyle(null);

                if (!success) {
                    Log.e("TabFragmentMap", "Removing style failed.");
                }
            }
        }
```

You should also return the `Switch` back to its previous checked state in both your `if (!success)` conditions and show a `Toast` to the users so they can understand what is happening.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've never worked with Wearables before.

Answer (score -1):

The else of this part:

```
            if(isChecked){
                boolean success = mGoogleMap.setMapStyle(new MapStyleOptions(getResources()
                        .getString(R.string.style_json)));

                if (!success) {
                    Log.e("TabFragmentMap", "Style parsing failed.");
                }
            }else{
                // What goes here?
                // mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            }
```

You need to uncomment it

```
            else {
                // What goes here?
                mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            }
```

Comment: That was uncommented in the first place but it STILL doesn't work.

Comment: Well then look at the other thing:                     boolean success = mGoogleMap.setMapStyle(new MapStyleOptions(getResources()
                            .getString(R.string.style_json))); is for activated, the opposite of that needs to go no in the else statement